# javascript adding strings together

Tags: javascript, string

```
var body = "jsonString=123";
var mybody = body.replace("jsonString=","");
console.log("mybody:"+mybody);
console.log("myhead:"+body.replace("jsonString=",""));
```

This this should give two equal outputs to console.log file but it doesnt!

```
Output:
mybody:
myhead:123
```

Can someone explain why variable mybody is blank?
Shouldnt it be 123?

**EDIT**
I am such a fool, there were some unrelated problems with my execution environment that led to this. It has nothing to do with javascript. 
Thanks for the help SO

Comment: That `should` work. Is that your actual code?

Comment: Works for me, the only thing I can think of is it's trying to add a string to the number 123, so you can convert `mybody` to a string like `mybody.toString()`

Comment: Where are you running this? I just copy and pasted your code into a node REPL console and I saw what you EXPECTED to see (i.e. mybody:123)

Comment: @JKirchartz But both follow the same form: `str+str`

Comment: im such a retard, can I delete this question after I give you guys points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is giving me the correct output per this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sc8xy/)

Results:

```
mybody:123
myhead:123
```